# Calculate prediction interval with stats::predict

Tags: forecasting, prediction-interval

I'm forecasting for the first time, so please for some patience.
I want to calculate lower bound of 95% interval on my point forecast. I have the following model for estimation and forecasting a certain value.

```
estimate.model <- arima(data$y, order = c(1, 0, 0), xreg = data$x_add, include.mean = FALSE)
forecast.model <- stats::predict(estimate.model, n.ahead = n.ahead, newxreg = newxreg)
```

`forecast.model` contains only `pred` and `se`. I've seen on multiple sites the possibility to add `interval = "predict"`, however not in the `stats` library. In this case, my model does not return any prediction intervals.

However, I've seen this calculation

```
upper_bound <- forecast.model$pred + 1.96* forecast.model$se
lower_bound <- forecast.model$pred - 1.96* forecast.model$se
```

but it doesn't seem quite right.

What is the proper way to calculate prediction intervals on point forecasts given the data I have?